# What does $\mathbb C(z)[x]$ denote?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, notation

I am currently reading a German book about complex analysis $($to be precise *K. Fritzsche: Grundkurs Funktionentheorie*$)$. Within the $4$th chapter he deals with elliptic functions and especially with the Weierstrass $\wp$ function. There he writes

> Let $\mathbb C(z)$ be the field of rational functions on $\mathbb C$ then we can define a ring homomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb C(z)[x]\to K(\Gamma)$ as
> $$\varphi\left(\sum_{i=0}^N R_i(x)x^i\right):=\sum_{i=0}^N R_i(\wp)\cdot(\wp')^i.$$

I am not sure whether I really understand the notation which is used here. I am used to $\mathbb F[x]$ refering to the polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb F$. Does the notation $\mathbb C(z)[x]$ simply refers to all polynomials with coefficients rational functions over $\Bbb C$ in $z$? This would match the later defined ring homomorphism $\varphi$ as $R(x)$ commonly denotes the rational functions in $x$ over $R$.

> Is my reasoning correct, i.e. does $\mathbb C(z)[x]$ denotes all polynomials of $x$ with coefficients in $\mathbb C(z)$, the field of rational functions in $z$ over $\Bbb C$, or am I missing something? Moreover is this a standard notation hence I have never seen a construct like this before.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct: $\mathbb C(z)[x]$ denotes all polynomials in $x$ with coefficients in $\mathbb C(z)$, the field of rational functions in $z$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Is this notation commonly used since, at least to me, it looks strange to write down two different parantheses behind the underlying field. But it could also be a purely aesthetic viewpoint of mine.

Comment: Not merely commonly used, but to my knowledge, the only notation used. What it says, it says very clearly.